# ActiveModel Serialization not taking effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to render how the specific attributes but all attributes are getting returned, it seems like AMS isn't having any effect.

Serializer:

```
class ImagesSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :facility_id, :title, :description
end
```

Comment: In `app/serializers/image_serializer.rb` define `class ImageSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer`

Comment: that worked thank you

Comment: Since when Batman is doing web-development?! Go back to Gotham and protect the people from the vilains, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your serializer should be called `ImageSerializer` (note absence of `s`), because your model is named `Image`.

And make sure the file is put under `app/serializers/image_serializer.rb`.